# CPU device not found

Tags: hpc, sycl

could someone please explain why I obtain this when I compile with clang++ fsycl and not for dpcpp

This is my device: Platform: Intel(R) OpenCL
Device: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5218 CPU @ 2.30GHz

```
CPU device not found. Error: No device of requested type available. -1 (CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND)
Falling back to default device selector...
```

Comment: This CPU does not have an associated GPU device so certainly no OpenCL device by default because the CPU-based implementation of OpenCL are AFAIK experimental and generally not available by default (you need to install such an implementation yourself). I guess OpenCL fail because it cannot find any implementation, even a fallback CPU one.

Comment: It works when I select the host device why is that the case. Is it bypassing OpenCL and assessing the cpu directly?

Comment: Yes, the host device typically does not use OpenCL, but generates the binaries that run on CPU at compile time.